# Geoserver SQL View does not pass multiple viewParams value from WMS to PostgreSQL function

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, wms

In my application, I am rendering Geoserver layer on map. Base database for Geoserver is PostGresql.

Below give is the request that call WMS layer. You can see, I am passing multiple viewParams as key value(layerid,centerlat and centerlong)

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?viewparams=layerid:9;centerlat:39.44043541908485;centerlong:-83.66638183593751&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=myWorkSpace%3Avw_GetLayerData&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&tiled=true&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=-9549125.069610499,4618019.500877211,-9470853.552646479,4696291.017841231
```

In Geoserver, I have created a view that run the below given script

```
select geom from fn_getlayerdata('%layerid%','%centerlat%','%centerlong%')
```

`fn_getlayerdata (integer,float,float)`: This is a function created in PostgreSQL.

Problem is that `fn_getlayerdata` function is not called. But If change the Geoserver view as given below it works.

```
select geom from fn_getlayerdata(%layerid%,88.78,-90.89)
```

function `fn_getlayerdata` returns table. Strange thing is that in `fn_getlayerdata` function value of `centerlat` and `centerlong` is not stored in `tempcenterlocation` table. Also there is no exception.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_getlayerdata(
                  layerid integer,centerlat float,centerlong float)
              RETURNS TABLE(geom geometry) 
              LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
           VOLATILE 
        AS $BODY$
       DECLARE exec_error VARCHAR;
      BEGIN

INSERT INTO tempcenterlocation(centerlat,centerlong)
values(centerlat,centerlong);
RETURN QUERY
select geom from myTable where dataid>=layerid;


 EXCEPTION WHEN Others THEN exec_error:=SQLERRM;
 Insert Into public."logtable" ("id","errormessage","idtype") VALUES 
      (10,exec_error,'fn_getlayerdata');
 END;

    $BODY$;

       ALTER FUNCTION fn_getlayerdata(integer,float,float)
           OWNER TO postgres;
```

Any Idea What wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

In the view, which you defined in GeoServer, you are passing all parameters as strings. Perhaps you should change the function's parameters' data types. Try converting them to strings and then cast them to integer/float inside the function, but first try with hardcoded values inside your function, without parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_getlayerdata()
  RETURNS TABLE(geom geometry) 
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  VOLATILE 
  AS $BODY$

BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY
  select geom from myTable where dataid>=9;

END;
$BODY$;
```

Also, you should check the GeoServer log for errors.

Comment: I have already tried this and no success. I got following error in log file DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find kvp parser for: 'layerid'. Storing as raw string.
DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find kvp parser for: 'centerlat'. Storing as raw string.
DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find kvp parser for: 'centerlong'. Storing as raw string.

Comment: In the geoserver sql view my statement was:                                                SELECT geom
from fn_getlayerdata('%layerid%','%centerlat%',
'%centerlong%')

Comment: It looks to me that we can not call Postgresql function in geoserver sql view.

Comment: @M.Sharma: it is possible, I have just tested it on my local GeoServer (v2.10.2), connecting po Postgres 9.4. Maybe try first creating a function without parameters, then add _layerid_ and then _centerlat_, _centerlong_. Also, try your function without DML statements - get rid of INSERT statements. (edit: I have edited the function body in my answer accordingly)